# Mac run mysql command in .sh file

Tags: mysql, macos, sh, zsh

I want to execute a mysql command from a test.sh file.
My file looks like this:

`#!/bin/zsh`

`mysql -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD' -h 'localhost' --port='9999'`

When I run it in the Terminal I get:

`test.sh:3: command not found: mysql`

I have defined an alias for the mysql command in .zshrc and .bashrc file:

`alias mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`

Interesting enough I can run/connect to mysql in the terminal and it works.
I have installed mysql with MAMP and I am using MacOS Ventura 13.0.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.zshrc` is read only when starting interactive shells, not shells run for scripts. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

You can put initialization code into `.zshenv`, which is read when starting any zsh process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Would you put in the Alias for mysql directly into the `.zshenv` file?

Comment: Actually, if it were me, I'd put it in your script. Then you don't have to worry about whether the `.zshenv` file has been edited if you move the script to another client machine.

Comment: @WhisperN : If it were me, I wouldn't make it an alias, but a script on its own. If you let your **scripts** rely on the content of .zshenv, it means that you can not give away your scripts to your fellow workers without asking them to modify their own .zshenv accordingly. This will soon become a maintenance nightmare.  Another possibility is to request mysql to be in your PATH, and then you don't need an alias at all.